# Why fprintf() function in my code don't working properly?

Tags: c++, printf

First fprintf() works as it has to work, but second output whole nonsense
[image]

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    FILE* f;
    fopen_s(&f, "text.txt", "w");
    std::string name = "hello";
    int area = 123;
    char ch = 'i';

    fprintf(f, "abc"); // OK

    fprintf(f, "|%-12s |%-5c |%-9d |", name.c_str(), area, ch); // not OK
}
```

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%s` format specifier expects a null-terminated array of `char`, not `std::string`.  Thus the `fprintf`'s behavior is undefined.

Use:

`fprintf(f, "|%-12s |%-5c |%-9d |", name.c_str(), area, ch);`

as the `c_str()` function returns the null-terminated array.

---

In addition, the format strings for the other types also seem incorrect.  To print an `int`, the format specifier is `%d`, not `%c`, and the format specify for char is `%c`, not `%d`.

Thus the final call to `fprintf` should be:

`fprintf(f, "|%-12s |%-5d |%-9c |", name.c_str(), area, ch);`